# Excel - Embedded PDF - "Change Icon" file name

Tags: microsoft-excel, icons, adobe-reader

Weird one. I am running a Win10Pro system with Office 2013 and Adobe Reader DC.

Whenever I embed a PDF object into Excel, the 'first' part works fine - I get a normal icon.

[image]

However, when I try to change the text below the icon, Excel doesn't seem to know where to find the icon any longer:

[image]

When I clock Browse, it just takes me to my Desktop folder.

I can browse to where AcroRd32 lives, and *then* things work:

[image]

Where my frustration lies is trying to figure out exactly *which* path Excel is using to retrieve the icons from the executable.

I can see icons for PDFs just fine on the desktop and via Windows Explorer, so it isn't an endemic/global problem.

Which registry key contains the path/file name used by Excel for the PDF 'Change Icon' dialog, so that I  can fix this issue once and for all?

Comment: Could you just confirm what you want to change the Caption or the ICON?

Comment: I basically want to change the caption when I do this process. However when I try to do so, it forgets where AcroRd32 is.

Comment: You are just a step behind, if you are trying to change the caption find the CAPTION Text box in your 2nd Screen Shot,,, and simply overwrite the File Path with desire Text.

Comment: You are not reading my question. When I want to change the caption Excel loses the path to AcroRd32 and I need to manually browse to it to get the PDF icon back. I want to fix this behaviour.

Comment: ,, It's natural when you try to change the Caption Excel shows the File Path coz it's the source and ICON can't be changed.!!

Comment: Excel shows an INCORRECT file path which cannot be resolved and must be browsed to manually. Please read my question again carefully.